# starting an activity for result from another activity that should return a result

Tags: android, start-activity

I have an Activity that starts another one for result. The fact is that I need to trigger another Activity for result from this one. Is this possible?

As an example Activity A calls Activity B for result, but Activity B needs to call Activity C for result to get the correct data.

I don't know if when I start Activity C for result, Activity B is going to send its (incomplete) result to the first calling activity (Activity A).

In case that it can be done, how should I handle the results from those activities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine. As long as Activity B is still running it will not trigger anything back to A until it finishes.

Launching A -> B -> C and then closing C will mean B's `onActivityResult` will trigger, then closing B will trigger A's `onActivityResult`.

So in Activity B you will need some logic like:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_C && resultCode == RESULT_XXX) {
        // Get the result from C, etc. Whatever you need to do
        String stuff = data.getStringExtra("XXX");
        Intent output = new Intent();
        output.putExtra(XXX, stuff);
        setResult(RESULT_XXX, output);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Then you can catch that back in Activity A.

Another option: if you find yourself needing to share data across a lot of activities and the logic seems to be getting complicated, you might like to consider using the **[Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)** class to store global state that you can access from all activities.

Comment: Thanks @KenWolf, I think with your first option it would work. I'll try it and tell you something! Thanks again!